# Chrome 22 Developer Tools - Global Sources Search not working right (ctrl-shift-f)

Tags: google-chrome, search, google-chrome-devtools

this morning I noticed my Chrome updated to Chrome 22 and that the search in the top right has been removed and can now be accessed with ctrl-f.

I also noticed that ctrl-shift-f is no longer working as expected... (but this is inconsistent)

The global search has been a huge time saver for me, and now sometimes it doesn't work until I've viewed a script at least once.

For example, I have 5 scripts that I know all contain "fn_init"

I search for fn_init and nothing comes up.

I open one of those scripts and then ctrl-shift-f again, and finally get a matching result for just the one file...

Is this working as intended?  Am I missing an option or something?  My dev tools config options are:

**General**

- Disabled cached

**Sources**

- Show folders checked
- Search in content scripts checked

Also: how can I install an older version of Chrome and stop it from updating automatically?

Comment: Could you provide an URL of the page where search does not show results for you? How are these scripts loaded (static <script> tags, dynamically added <script> elements, evals with sourceURL)?

Comment: This happens randomly for the same page.  I can't give a specific example as it's not my IP.  I can say that is a one page app based on Liferay & Backbone with portlets which dynamically append <script> to the head through javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get an older version of Chrome your best bet is to find a build of Chromium from https://chromium-build.appspot.com/p/chromium/console however if this if for devtools stability you are missing out on a lot of new features and bug fixes.

As for Search across all files it is still there and CTRL-SHIFT-F on Windows and CMD-OPT-F on Mac.  See Addy Osmani's post https://plus.google.com/115133653231679625609/posts/e4W2kdrFJY9

If you find issues as bugs, it is better to raise the issue on http://crbug.com/new as it will get direct attention from the engineering team there.